# Import PCL android studio

Tags: java, c++, android-studio, point-cloud-library, point-clouds

How can I import Point cloud library ( http://pointclouds.org/ ) in android studio?

I need to use some *.cpp and *.h files because I want to filter my point cloud files and do other things with the Project Tango.

How can I do that? Is there another way to use PCL in android studio, maybe in Java?

I'm running Xubuntu 16.04 64 bit

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You may compile PCL for Android following the guide [here](https://github.com/PointCloudLibrary/pcl/wiki/Android)